# Excel 2007: XML: choking on missing ss: namespace qualifier

Tags: c#, xml, excel, xml-namespaces

Trying to create an Excel 2007 XML file, using C# and System.XML.Serialization.  The root element of an Excel XML file is such:

```
<Workbook xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
```

Many elements within the default namespace, have attributes qualified with 'ss', which is unnecessary as both 'ss' and the default namespace are both "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet".

For example the Style element, appears as:

```
   <Style ss:ID="s21">
      <Font x:Family="Swiss" ss:Bold="1"/>
   </Style>
```

When I create my XmlSerializerNamespaces, I add all the namespaces, that Excel wants:

```
var ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
ns.Add("", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet");
ns.Add("o", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
ns.Add("x", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel");
ns.Add("ss", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet");
ns.Add("html", "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40");
```

In the generated XML, the "" (default) namespace is omitted because it is the same as 'ss'.

My style object is something along the lines of:
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet")]
    public class Styles
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string ID { get; set; }

```
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string Font { get; set; }
}
```

When I actually generate the XML I am getting:

```
<ss:Style ID="s21">
          <ss:Font x:Family="Swiss" Bold="1"/>
</ss:Style>
```

I don't think there is anything technically wrong with this. Excel doesn't mind the ss: qualifier on the elements, but it chokes because it can't the 'ID' attribute of Style.  It must be hardcoded to look for the literal string 'ss:ID'?

If I omit the 'ss' from the namespaces it produces cleaner XML, but does not make my error go away. I have also tried omitting the 'ss' namespace, and then setting the namespace of the Style object to be literally 'ss', but it generates some temporary namespace named 'd4p1' and makes a real mess.

Any ideas on how to make Excel read valid XML?

And for bonus marks, how can I make the begginning of my XML file look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
```

Obviously the first part comes with an XML writer, but is there any non-hackish ways to get that second line?

Thanks,
~S

Answer (score 0):

Rather than writing the xml yourself, did you consider using the [Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en)? Besides helping with the manipulation of Open XML docs, it also contains quite a bit of documentation, and seems like it would be well suited for your task:

> The Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office is built on top of the
>   System.IO.Packaging API and provides
>   strongly typed part classes to
>   manipulate Open XML documents. The SDK
>   also uses the .NET Framework
>   Language-Integrated Query (LINQ)
>   technology to provide strongly typed
>   object access to the XML content
>   inside the parts of Open XML
>   documents.

Comment: I don't have a lot of faith in MS technologies working together, nor their ability to figure out XML right now, but I'll give it a try anyway.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This worked, but the SDK is pretty low level, and not nearly as convenient as the package I had written.